# How to install hokuyo_node/urg_node on kinetic?

Tags: ros, lidar, urg-node, ros-kinetic, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I bought a Hokuyo URG-04LX-UG01 lidar today, but I can't use it with ROS kinetic.

Untill now [hokuyo_node wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node) still doesn't have a kinetic release. The newest release is for jade.

So I tried to install hokuyo_node from source. Firstly I cloned [hokuyo_node source](https://github.com/ros-drivers/hokuyo_node) from github to my local directory `~/catkin_ws/src`. Then I did `catkin_make`. The result is as follow:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "driver_base" with
any of the following names:

driver_baseConfig.cmake
driver_base-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "driver_base" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"driver_base_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"driver_base" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
hokuyo_node/CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'driver_base'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "driver_base" with
any of the following names:

driver_baseConfig.cmake
driver_base-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "driver_base" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"driver_base_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"driver_base" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
hokuyo_node/CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/shay/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/shay/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

It seems that I need the `driver_base` package. But kinetic doesn't have a `driver_base`. As `driver_base` had been deprecated.

Is there anyone uses hokuyo lidar on Kinetic? Any help would be appreciated, Thx. :)

---

EDIT

Thanks to @130s, I tried `urg_node` just now. `urg_node` also hasn't been released to Kinetic, So I tried to intall it from source.  I cloned [urg_node source](https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_node) from github to my local directory `~/catkin_ws/src`. Then I did `catkin_make`. The result is as follow:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "urg_c" with any of
  the following names:

    urg_cConfig.cmake
    urg_c-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "urg_c" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "urg_c_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "urg_c"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  urg_node/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'urg_c'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "urg_c" with any of
  the following names:

    urg_cConfig.cmake
    urg_c-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "urg_c" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "urg_c_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "urg_c"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  urg_node/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/shay/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/shay/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

So I need the package `urg_c`, but `urg_c` also hasn't been released to Kinetic.

What should I do, go back to `jade`?(~_~)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243232/how-to-install-hokuyo_node/urg_node-on-kinetic?/) by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 763 on 2016-09-07

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KevinNickels](https://answers.ros.org/users/6631/kevinnickels/) on 2017-05-11**:
I also had to clone and build laser_proc and urg_c packages

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/laser_proc.git
git clone https://github.com/ros-dirvers/urg_c.git
cd ..
catkin_make
```

**Comment by [kasptom](https://answers.ros.org/users/35272/kasptom/) on 2019-05-22**:
@KevinNickels, there is a typo in the repo clone link, should be:

`git clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_c.git`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need to install and compile driver_base from sources too

```
git clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/driver_common.git
```

First compile driver_common and then you should be able to compile hokuyo_node

---

Originally posted by [JorgeArino](https://answers.ros.org/users/20071/jorgearino/) with karma: 96 on 2016-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) on 2016-09-08**:
Yeah, I make it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These days the [hokuyo_node wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node#For_newer_ROS_distro_than_Indigo) recommends [urg_node](http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node) package. And it's still true that `urg_node` hasn't been released into Kinetic, for which I [requested](https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_node/issues/21).

One advantage despite it's the probably more maintained package with more updates, `urg_node` is BSD while `hokuyo_node` is LGPL.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) on 2016-09-08**:
Thanks, I tried `urg_node` and edit and question. It seems that I have to go back to jade temporarily and wait for `urg_node` and `hokuyo_node` to release to Kinetic.